# Sending Authorization Header with JWT in HTTP-Request

Tags: html, http-headers, authorization, jwt

I'm having trouble getting my stateless authorization to work.

I currently have my server adding the Authorization header with the generated JWT to the HTTPResponse for the client.

My problem is the Client-side of things. I'm not quite understanding how to get the header I added on the HTTP-Response to send back in all HTTP-Requests. I've been trying to use the `Bearer` schema and tried without any schema but nothing seems to be working. I am not using OAuth so I'm not sure if the `Bearer` schema works without it. I've also tried `Basic` and `Digest`.

This is how it looks when I send it from the server.

```
Authorization: Bearer s5la8kdj4flak2.l4as5kdjfow2ie.owekj6nvowe4i3ej
```

My question is really, how do I send this Authorization header back to the server to be authenticated?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to send an Authentication header back and forth the way I was asking above. You would have to be explicitly be using `Basic Authorization`, which I was not.

The way I ended up doing it was making a cookie named `Authorization` where the body had the `JWT`. Cookies are automatically sent back to the server in the `HTTPRequest`, where I was able to strip it out in a custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

Put JWT into cookie, this will protect it against theft by XSS attack